# where to add if then else to WordPress page in any of the WordPress editors?

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, posts

where to put the code or do I need a plugin?

videos link to a videos page created in wordpress and need to show the if it has posts else "Sorry nothing found"

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'videos',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'category_name' => 'videos'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="superhero-container">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="superhero">                     
                <?php if ( get_the_post_thumbnail() ) : /* Show the featured image if there is one */ ?>                                     
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The wordpress query loop is not showing nothing found hence the code option above

wordpres query loop not working hence the code option

Comment: 'category_name' is for the category taxonomy, if you have a custom taxonomy you'll need to use `tax_query`. Try commenting that out, you'll see some results

Comment: wordpress query loop is not showing "Nothing found", It posts the title of the post that doesn't even exist.


page.php is being used to display this content and I need to edit or add code in here to show "No videos" otherwise show the posts that actually do exist

Answer (score 0):

I think its working sorry u didn't understand my query. Used the default wordpress query loop and wasn't aware that a post existed already linked to the videos category, with no title. thanks again!
Have a great day further! :)

[Wordpress provides a query loop with a NO results block, the image explains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VThSk.png)